Azure Log Analytics KQL: How to project specific key values from the dynamically sized AuditLog AdditionalDetails field
"How can I find a specific element in a dynamic array in KQL?"
I am attempting to generate a table of privileged role activations over a period.
Amongst others I want to have columns for the attributes TicketSystem and TicketNumber.
These appear in the field AdditionalProperties.  This seems to be a dynamiccaly seized list or array.
But as this is a list or array of dynamic size (some fields are optional and not always present) I can not index a fixed position.  I have to search inside the elements for the appropriate key names
instead.
I now have something along these lines:
AuditLogs
| where TimeGenerated > now() - 7d
| where Category == 'RoleManagement'
| where
    TargetResources contains "Global Administrator"
    and
    (
        OperationName contains "Add member to role completed (PIM activation)"
            or OperationName contains "Add eligible member to role in PIM completed"
            or OperationName contains "Add member to role outside of PIM"
            or OperationName contains "Add member to role request approved (PIM activation)"
    )
| extend _InitiatedByUPN = parse_json(InitiatedBy.user.userPrincipalName)
| extend _Target_displayName = parse_json(TargetResources).[0].displayName
| extend _Target_type = parse_json(TargetResources).[1].type
| extend AD = parse_json(AdditionalDetails)
| project format_datetime(ActivityDateTime,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), Identity, _InitiatedByUPN, OperationName, _Target_displayName, ResultReason, AD.TicketSystem, AD.TicketNumber

But it gives empty entries for the columns AD.TicketSystem and AD.TicketNumber.
I have tried various modifications based on comparable questions and answers, but all fail.

Can you give (in your question) an examle how AdditionalDetails looks like? Just query only this field.

With: AuditLogs | project AdditionalDetails

I´ve added a answer which might answer your question. Please check it out.

Did my post answer your question?

I have created a sample based on your query. So to answer your question:
Use mv-expand AdditionalDetails, like this:
let AuditLogs = datatable (
    TimeGenerated: datetime,
    Category: string,
    TargetResources: string,
    OperationName: string,
    InitiatedBy: dynamic,
    AdditionalDetails: dynamic,
    ActivityDateTime: datetime,
    Identity: string,
    ResultReason: string
)
[
    datetime(2024-06-28T10:00:00Z), "RoleManagement", '[{"displayName":"Global Administrator"},{"type":"Role"}]', "Add member to role completed (PIM activation)", dynamic({"user":{"userPrincipalName":"user1@example.com"}}), dynamic([{"key":"TicketSystem", "value":"ServiceNow"}, {"key":"TicketNumber", "value":"INC001"}]), datetime(2024-06-28T10:00:00Z), "user1", "Success",
    datetime(2024-06-29T11:00:00Z), "RoleManagement", '[{"displayName":"Global Administrator"},{"type":"Role"}]', "Add eligible member to role in PIM completed", dynamic({"user":{"userPrincipalName":"user2@example.com"}}), dynamic([{"key":"TicketSystem", "value":"Jira"}, {"key":"TicketNumber", "value":"TKT002"}]), datetime(2024-06-29T11:00:00Z), "user2", "Success",
    datetime(2024-06-30T12:00:00Z), "RoleManagement", '[{"displayName":"Global Administrator"},{"type":"Role"}]', "Add member to role outside of PIM", dynamic({"user":{"userPrincipalName":"user3@example.com"}}), dynamic([{"key":"TicketSystem", "value":"ServiceNow"}, {"key":"TicketNumber", "value":"INC003"}, {"key":"TicketNumber", "value":"INC004"}, {"key":"TicketNumber", "value":"INC005"}]), datetime(2024-06-30T12:00:00Z), "user3", "Failure",
    datetime(2024-07-01T13:00:00Z), "RoleManagement", '[{"displayName":"Global Administrator"},{"type":"Role"}]', "Add member to role request approved (PIM activation)", dynamic({"user":{"userPrincipalName":"user4@example.com"}}), dynamic([{"key":"TicketSystem", "value":"Jira"}, {"key":"TicketNumber", "value":"TKT004"}]), datetime(2024-07-01T13:00:00Z), "user4", "Success",
    datetime(2024-07-02T14:00:00Z), "RoleManagement", '[{"displayName":"Global Administrator"},{"type":"Role"}]', "Add member to role completed (PIM activation)", dynamic({"user":{"userPrincipalName":"user5@example.com"}}), dynamic([{"key":"TicketSystem", "value":"ServiceNow"}, {"key":"TicketNumber", "value":"INC005"}]), datetime(2024-07-02T14:00:00Z), "user5", "Success",
    datetime(2024-07-03T15:00:00Z), "RoleManagement", '[{"displayName":"User"},{"type":"Role"}]', "Add member to role outside of PIM", dynamic({"user":{"userPrincipalName":"user6@example.com"}}), dynamic([{"key":"TicketSystem", "value":"Jira"}, {"key":"TicketNumber", "value":"TKT006"}]), datetime(2024-07-03T15:00:00Z), "user6", "Failure"
];
AuditLogs
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(7d)
| where Category == 'RoleManagement'
| where
    TargetResources contains "Global Administrator"
    and
    (
        OperationName contains "Add member to role completed (PIM activation)"
            or OperationName contains "Add eligible member to role in PIM completed"
            or OperationName contains "Add member to role outside of PIM"
            or OperationName contains "Add member to role request approved (PIM activation)"
    )
| extend _InitiatedByUPN = InitiatedBy.user.userPrincipalName
| extend _Target_displayName = parse_json(TargetResources)[0].displayName
| extend _Target_type = parse_json(TargetResources)[1].type
| mv-expand AdditionalDetails
| extend TicketSystem = tostring(AdditionalDetails.key) 
| extend TicketNumber = tostring(AdditionalDetails.value) 
| project format_datetime(ActivityDateTime,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 
          Identity, 
          _InitiatedByUPN, 
          OperationName, 
          _Target_displayName, 
          ResultReason,
          TicketSystem,
          TicketNumber


mv-expand expands the list and make it flat. You will get one line
more per item in that list. So if that array has 5 Items, you will get
5 more lines in the result. If you need to filter just add a where clause after mv-expand to find only one specific element.

Find the sample Code here.
Result:


Thanks for your reply.  Apologies for delay.
I tried your appraoch, as follows:
| mv-expand AdditionalDetails
| extend TicketSystem = tostring(AdditionalDetails.value)
| extend TicketNumber = tostring(AdditionalDetails.value)
| project format_datetime(ActivityDateTime,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), Identity, OperationName, ResultReason, TicketSystem, TicketNumber, ActivityDisplayName, LoggedByService

But I can not manage to filter e.g. using | where AdditionalDetails.key == 'TicketSystem'

Have you used: | mv-expand AdditionalDetails | extend TicketSystem = tostring(AdditionalDetails.key)  | extend TicketNumber = tostring(AdditionalDetails.value) and then where TicketSystem == "something"

Also try it out in my sample code link. there you can test it as well.

I have changed the sample code in my answer a bit to show the where clause.
